# Why does R add "%22" to the file path when rendering a rendering a bookdown file to html

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

When I run:

`bookdown::render_book("index.Rmd", "bookdown::gitbook")`

The HTML output has the wrong filepath since it adds %22 before and after the file path.

I am able to delete this and it upload correctly, but its inconvenient to delete these from every figure everytime an update is made.

Comment: Thats odd %22 is the encoding for the double quotes.  You run the command from the console?

Comment: yes from the console

Comment: If you create a new, nearly blank Rmd file and run render_book, does the same thing happen? Or is the problem specific to your index.Rmd file. What version of R and bookdown are you using? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.